# Retrieve parameters from hosts and insert them to variable in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

In my hosts I declare a group with ips. some of the Ips has parameters.
While the playbook is running, I want to declare a variable that will hold the value of the param in the hosts.
I want to use the value in the variable as a parameter to a python script or without variable, just be able to send a parameter value to a script.

```
[cluster]
1.1.1.1 name1=value1
2.2.2.2 name2=value2
3.3.3.3
```

### in the playbook:

```
- script: "/home/ansible/pyScript/test.py {{ /*something that contains: value1*/ }} "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: run shell script
  script: testscript.sh {{ name1 }}
  register: testscript_result
```

you should be able to use the host variable using {{ name1 }}. For example, the above script will take the value of name1 as the first parameter for the script.

Comment: Can I insert this param value to a variable prior to running my script? The reason is that I want to run the script only on the first host,but with the value of the param from the second host. 10X

Comment: yes, and BTW name1 is already a variable you can use it the way you want to.